# how to stop automatic conversion from int to float and vice-versa in std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, std

I wrote a small program of using `std::map` here as follows.

```
int main()
{
  map<int,float>m1;
  m1.insert(pair<int,float>(10,15.0));   //step-1
  m1.insert(pair<float,int>(12.0,13));   //step-2
  cout<<"map size="<<m1.size()<<endl;    //step -3
```

I created a map with int type as key and float type as value(key-value) pair for the map m1

1. Created a normal int-float pair and inserted to map.
2. Created a cross float-int pair and inserted to map. Now I know that implicit conversion is making this pair to get inserted to map.

Here I just don't want the implicit conversion to take place and compiler error should be given.

What sort of changes I have to do in this program/map to make the comipiler flag an error while we try to do step-2 type operation?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a suggestion:

```
template <typename K, typename V, typename W>
void map_insert(map<K,V>& m, K k, W w) {
  V v = w;
  m.insert(pair<K,V>(k,v));
}

int main() {
  map<int,float>m1;
  map_insert(m1, 10, 15.0);
  map_insert(m1, 12.0, 13);  // compiler complains here
  cout<<"map size="<<m1.size()<<endl;
```

The third template parameter is a bit awkward but is necessary to allow casting from `double` to `float`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the third template parameter is necessary?

Comment: Without it, the compiler complains that it cannot match template parameters for the first map_insert() call, since 15.0 is a double, not a float.

Comment: This is hardly a solution (or answer) to his problem: it's just a completely different API that avoids constructing a std::pair all together. Although in that sense it would "work", it also falls in the category trivial.

Comment: @CarloWood The OP phrased his question as "What sort of changes I have to do in this program/map to make the comipiler flag an error while we try to do step-2 type operation?"

Notice how he uses the phrase "step-2 type operation", rather than "std::map.insert() call". Also notice how he asks about what changes he needs to his "program/map". In my opinion, this implies he is in fact looking for a solution like the one I suggest. But I could be wrong, the OP will let us know.

Comment: Your solution also doesn't appear to move properly, making redundant copies.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09c517d0ead4c024

Comment: @MooingDuck The code in your link doesn't quite look like the code in my answer. Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: @dshin: Compare the number of constructor calls in yours: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cdc156a488fecb3 (13) to mine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59eebda849ff693d (7).  Your code makes redundant copies.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible (and even if it is possible, then it would be **major** hack that you shouldn't use).

`insert` takes a `value_type` as argument, which is a `pair<int const,float>`.
So, when you try to insert a `pair<float, int>`, the compiler looks for a conversion, that is: a constructor of `pair<int const, float>` that takes a `pair<float, int>` as argument, which simply exists. In fact, I tried to come up with a partial specialization for that template member (that allows the conversion) which then you could have fail on the remaining template parameter, but I failed to do so; it seems not possible. Anyway, it would be a very dirty hack that you just shouldn't be doing just to avoid a typo. Elsewhere you might need this conversion, and it's a no no to define anything in namespace std anyway.

So what is the solution to "How can I avoid this kind of typos?" ?

Here is what I usually do:

1) All my maps have a typedef for their type.
2) I then use `::value_type` (and `::iterator` etc) on that type exclusively.

This is not only more robust, it is also more flexible: you can change the container type later on and the code is likely to still work.

So, your code would become:

```
int main()
{
  typedef std::map<int,float> m_type;
  m_type m1;

  m1.insert(m_type::value_type(10,15.0));   // allowed
  m1.insert(m_type::value_type(12.0,13));   // no risk for a typo.
```

An alternative solution would be to wrap your `float` in a custom class. This isn't a bad thing to do anyway for (again) reasons of flexibility. It is rarely nice to have written code using a `std::map<int, builtin-type>` to then realize you need to store more data, and believe me that happens a lot. You might as well start with a class from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

There may well be a simpler way but this is what occurred to me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template<typename Key, typename Value>
struct typesafe_pair
{
    const Key& key;
    const Value& value;
    explicit typesafe_pair(const Key& key, const Value& value): key(key), value(value) {}

    operator typename std::map<Key, Value>::value_type() { return typename std::map<Key, Value>::value_type(key, value); }
};

int main()
{
  std::map<int,float>m1;

  m1.insert(std::pair<int,float>(10,15.0));   // allowed
  m1.insert(std::pair<float,int>(12.0,13));   // allowed!!

  m1.insert(typesafe_pair<int,float>(10, 15.0)); // allowed
  m1.insert(typesafe_pair<float, int>(12.0, 13)); // compiler error

  std::cout << "map size=" << m1.size() << std::endl;    //step -3
}
```

**EDIT: 1** Someone may be able to provide a better (more efficient) solution involving rvalue references and perfect forwarding magic that I don't quite grasp yet.

**EDIT 2:** I think ***Carlo Wood*** has the best solution IMHO.